# Is there a way to get the edit URL for a tag wiki from the API?

Tags: support, feature-request, api, api-v2, tag-wiki

I've been playing with a little webapp for tags of a certain kind for travel.SE [(current pre-alpha version gist on github)](https://gist.github.com/1513820).

One thing I would like to do is add links for the various tag-related functions on the actual SE site for each tag.

But I realized that the while most tag related URLs use the tag's name, the edit URL uses some internal tag ID. For example for the [codeigniter](/questions/tagged/codeigniter) here on StackApps we (currently) have this URL:

> [`https://stackapps.com/edit-tag-wiki/2705`](https://stackapps.com/edit-tag-wiki/2705)

Now the thing is I can't find anywhere in the API that will provide either this ID or this URL. Have I missed something or is this a feature I should request for the future?

Comment: If you visit http://stackapps.com/edit-tag-wiki/codeigniter - you're redirected to that URL.  If you don't mind the redirect, you might just be able to get around it that way.

Comment: You should submit this as an answer @agent86! Is it documented somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you visit:

```
http://stackapps.com/edit-tag-wiki/codeigniter
```

... you're redirected to that URL. If you don't mind the redirect, you might just be able to get around it that way.

As far as I know, there's no documentation about when you can specify a name versus when you must specify an ID number, and I know of no API route that returns the ID numbers.  The routes that return "tag" objects conform to [this object specification.](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/tag)

Comment: Ah yes now I such URLs when I hover over tag edit links. Never noticed them before. Thanks!